# Eclipse Availiable driver templates are emty

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, mysql-connector

[image]I can't find any solution to my problem. When I try to add MySql Window->Preferences->Driver definitions, then Vendor Filter-> MySql I don't see any template, any Jar List. That happens with every vendor.
[image]

Comment: You should download mySql driver for java and in driver section click brows button and add mySql driver in to eclipse.visit [hear](https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/add-mysql-jdbc-driver-to-eclipse.html)

Comment: that is the problem that there is nothing here

Comment: Are any drivers listed on tab "JAR List"?

Comment: No, and I can't added

Answer (score 1):

The driver list is hidden. You need to resize the window to show the complete list.

[image]

[image: Resize by dragging the window]